# Scatterplot of clustered data, to show Clusters and Centers

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, scatter-plot

I found the better number of clusters and my clusters for eacch data.

Now hoe can i plot my scatter based on centers and clusters to see datas?

This is my dataset.

[image]

This is code i using.

```
x = df_diabetes_normalizado['Glicose']
y = df_diabetes_normalizado['Massa Corporal']
Cluster = df_diabetes_normalizado['clusters']
centers = np.random.randn(1, 2) 

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,9))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
scatter = ax.scatter(x,y,c=Cluster,s=50)
for i,j in centers:
    ax.scatter(i,j,s=50,c='red',marker='+')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')

fig.show()
```

However the plot is so cofuse for me.

[image]

Could you please give me some guide how i can fix my script to generare my correct scater based in centers and clustering distribution?

Comment: what do you mean with better plot? This is working, the problem probably is, that you have more then two variables wich are influencing your cluster.

Comment: I want to create a scatter with 2 class variating in my clusters. But i not getting.

Comment: Could you please post the URL to the dataset? rather than an image of the dataset? to make this reproducible for the rest of us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Because**

1. **You're plotting the wrong variable: your dependent variable should be 'Classe' (1/0, presumably for diabetic or not)** Not 'clusters', which is merely an integer telling you how many clusters exhibit those characteristics, not whether they're in `Classe==0` or `1`.
2. clearly you have 8 variables ('Numero Gravida', 'Glicose', 'Pressao', ..., 'Idade') and **your dependent variable ('Classe') is a function of all 8 of them**, not just the two you arbitrarily picked to plot: x='Glicose' and y='Massa Corporal'.

1) `clusters` is merely an integer telling you how many clusters exhibit those characteristics, not whether each cluster is in `Classe==0` or `1`.

```
    Cluster = df_diabetes_normalizado['clusters']
    ...
    scatter = ax.scatter(x,y,c=Cluster, ...)
```

Your plot is wrongly using color to show `c=Cluster` i.e. the number of clusters, you're not plotting `Classe` anywhere. Plot `Classe` instead. (You might choose to use `size=Clusters`, so larger clusters plot larger)

2) 'Generate the correct scatterplot [of two variables]' is not well-defined; clearly you have 8 variables ('Numero Gravida', 'Glicose', 'Pressao', ..., 'Idade') and **your dependent variable ('Classe') is a function of all 8 of them**, not just the two you arbitrarily picked to plot: x='Glicose' and y='Massa Corporal'.

- Assuming you don't want to do a 3D or n-dimensional plot, you either do:
- some dimensional reduction with **PCA (Principal Component Analysis)**, then plot the most important two/three pseudovariables (see e.g. [this example](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/PCA-plots-of-the-intestinal-microbiome-The-four-panels-show-the-bacterial-community-at_fig3_331224510)...)
- or else build a model based on a custom cluster distance function.

If you post MCVE for your dataset, and you tell us what sort of plot you actually want, then can post code.

Answer (score 1):

Example using `iris` dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn import datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:,0:2]
y = iris.target

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4)
kmeans.fit(X)

assignments = kmeans.labels_ # this is the CLUSTERS column in your case
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
classes = np.unique(assignments)
colors= ['r','b','k','y'] # 4 CLUSTERS SO 4 COLORS HERE
for s,l in enumerate(classes):
    xs = X[:,0] 
    ys = X[:,1] 
    plt.scatter(xs[assignments==s], ys[assignments==s], c = colors[s]) # color based on group
plt.plot(kmeans.cluster_centers_[0][0], kmeans.cluster_centers_[0][1], 'ro',markersize=16, alpha = 0.5, label='')
plt.plot(kmeans.cluster_centers_[1][0], kmeans.cluster_centers_[1][1], 'bo',markersize=16, alpha = 0.5)
plt.plot(kmeans.cluster_centers_[2][0], kmeans.cluster_centers_[2][1], 'ko',markersize=16, alpha = 0.5)
plt.plot(kmeans.cluster_centers_[3][0], kmeans.cluster_centers_[3][1], 'yo',markersize=16, alpha = 0.5)
plt.grid()
```

[image]